# asp:RequiredFieldValidator and radiobuttons

Tags: asp.net, validation

This is my first question in stackoverflow.com.

I am working on a school project which I have to validate the input from the user. Everytime the page load, it give the server error message. Please see the codes, and the error message after.

```
<div>
<table>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validateCheck" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="RadioButton1"   ErrorMessage="Please Enter" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>             
</td>
</table>
</div>
```

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Control 'RadioButton1' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'validateCheck' cannot be validated.
```

Answer (score 7):

The RequiredFieldValidator does not validate a RadioButton. However, you can use the RadioButtonList control instead (validated by RequiredFieldValidator).

Answer (score 3):

The asp:RadioButton do not support validation, instead of RadioButton use a RadioButtonList:'

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</div>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

</form>
```